# Help please - installed ubuntu 18.04 lts - cant get ethernet/wifi working

Tags: 18.04, drivers, wireless, ethernet

I have a dell optiplex 9010 desktop PC. I have just installed ubuntu 18.04, alongside windows 10, on my hard disc in a separate partition. All is ok except I cannot establish an internet connection.
When I go onto settings> Wi-fi.....it says no wifi adapter found. I have tried running an ethernet cable from laptop to desktop but it will not establish a connection. I then tried tethering my mobile phone and this allowed me to go online however I still cant figure out how to install the drivers!!

Using my laptop (packard bell) I have looked online for the drivers for these devices only because I am assuming the device drivers are not present, I downloaded from an intel web site what I think are the related drivers. The name on the file to be extracted was e1000e-3.8.4.tar.gz.
I have extracted these files to a usb stick but have no idea if 1) This is the probable fix and 2) if it is how can I upload these drivers to my desktop. (my desktop is an optiplex 9010)

I am very new to linux and following some suggestions online I used the terminal command 'lspci' and this showed the following what I believe to be wifi/ethernet related devices on the system:

1. ethernet controller [0200]:intel corp 82579LM gigabit network connection.
   Subsystem: Dell 82579LM gigabit network connection.
   Kernel driver in use: e1000e.
   Kernel modules: e1000e
2. ethernet controller [0200]:intel corp 82572EI gigabit ethernet controller. Subsystem: intel corp PRO/1000PT server adapter [8086:1082]
   Kernel driver in use: e1000e.
   Kernel modules: e1000e

I have two ethernet cards in my desktop.

1. Intel PRO/1000PT server adapter 82572EI and...
2. Intel 82579LM gigabit network connection...

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The e1000e module is provided with the standard repositories.  Ensure your Dell firmware is up to date and look for "missing firmware" messages:  dmesg |egrep -i "fw|firm"

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will check online how I can tell if the firmware is up to date or not. If honest I dont understand what 'standard respositories stand for/what they are but it has given me something to look into.

Comment: I have not noticed any messages that relate to 'missing firmware' ...but I will look for them. When would these message likely occur?

Comment: At power-on, the missing firmware messages wouild show up with in a few seconds.  The e1000e module is present on my 20.04 Ubuntu, and I don't even have that hardware, so I doubt it's missing on your system.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will restart my system and look for messages in line with what you suggest. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I have booted up windows (I have win 10 on one partition and ubuntu on another) - both of the ethernet devices were showing as not working. I tried the 'troubleshoot' option and the 82579LM gigabit network controller device did not work but the PRO/1000PT did. I managed to log onto internet.

Comment: I then went onto dell web site and it told me I needed to upgrade firmware (I did as you suggested and checked for firmware error related messages....and didnt see any) I have not done this yet as I am concerned given that one controller works in windows then the firmware version is not the issue.....BTW thats only me guessing, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This might or might not be a relevant point but when I boot windows the display is not great, colours do not seem correct etc (when i boot ubuntu display is fine.....this probably doesnt help but I am just saying what i see as I dont know enough to decide whats relevant and what is not).

Comment: If there is any further help you can give me it would be appreciated, but I am thinking I should go to local computer tech with linux experience.....if I can find one where I live.